# How to print all increasing-index triplets in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, triplet

Given an array `ar` of length `n`, how can I print all triplets `(ar[i], ar[j], ar[k])` in better than `O(n^3)` time where `0<=i<j<=k<n` ?

Example Input:

```
ar[]={5,6,7}

Output:

5 6 6
5 6 7
6 7 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Suppose that the array has `n` elements.  Included in the output is each combination of values from the first third of the array, second third, and third third.  That right there is `n^3/27 = O(n^3)` output.

You cannot produce `O(n^3)` output with less than `O(n^3)` work.